# Azure Release Pipelines: Azure SQL Database deployment error with not able to get to database server

Tags: sql, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are seeing an error when trying to run a .SQL file on our Azure Dev Ops release pipeline:

[image]

Here is the error:

**System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: No resource found with serverName [the server], serverType Microsoft.Sql/servers in subscription [subscription id]. Specify the correct serverName/serverType and try again.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-**

We do have this set to checked on the networking tab of the sql server database:

[image]

I've checked the database server name and everything is correct.

It has something to do with the firewall rules though, but we can't figure out why we can't release our migration scripts to run auto.

Any other ideas of what else we can try?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

We have about 5 other instances that are set up the same way that seem to work fine.

**Update 2:**

Here is the Release step we are doing to push a `.sql` file to Azure Database which is failing:

[image]
[image]

Comment: That 'Allow Azure services .........' option does not include everything in Azure.  The information icon should lead you to page listing what is included.  I doubt DevOps pipelines are included.  You may have to configure a Self Hosted pool that can be allowed through the server firewall - that could run on an Azure VM.  Have done this for deploying App Services on a private VNet.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger: Thanks for your response. One thing I didn't add, was we have like 5 others that operate the same way, that seem to work fine. So that is where we are confused.

Comment: There are numerous ways to run .sql files in devops. Looks like you are using the one that includes a step that tries to find the Azure SQL Server in the control plane and opens the firewall. This step may not even be necessary. You could add some more detail about which step your release pipleine is using. For this error in particular, I guess your Azure SQL Server is not visible to the service connection that you are using

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I added the full release step we are doing to push the `.sql` file to our azure database. Still not understanding while we have others that work? Seems like it might be a setting on our Azure database? We can't find what setting we need to change though! Thanks for looking and responding to this post.

Comment: Firstly keep in mind that YAML pipleines are now the recommended approach. What you have here is the "release" flavour which is generally not recommended for new work. Anyway, whatever service connection this step is using probably doesn't have control plane access to the Azure SQL Server. It's hard to give more details because I only do YAML now

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Maybe that is it? Maybe the new ones need to be made a different way and they've blocked the way to connect to SQL db. I can look into that. I'll try to keep you updated. Thanks for responding with your suggestions.

Comment: You need to do more sleuthing and work out what is different between the working Azure SQL and the non working ones

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Yep, my co-worker was looking into that or possibly putting a ticket in to Microsoft and seeing what they see.

Comment: Basically you need to look at the RBAC for each Azure SQL instance and compare them. The service connection is probalby set up for all of the Azure SQL Servers except the one you need

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: posted what seems to have fixed the issue. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

We removed the **tcp:** of of the `server=` part of the connection string and it worked.

Failed:

```
Server=tcp:server.database.azure.net,1433;Initial Catalog=[enter-db-nm];Persist Security Info=False;User ID=[enter-userid];Password=[enter-pw];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;App={0}
```

Worked:

```
Server=server.database.azure.net,1433;Initial Catalog=[enter-db-nm];Persist Security Info=False;User ID=[enter-userid];Password=[enter-pw];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;App={0}
```

We could leave the **tcp:** of of the `server=` and open up all ip addresses and it would work.

Suppose the `tcp` does something on the back side.

You can use the **tcp:** fine with logging into the database from SSMS.